# Tracking NSTextView changes with NSDocument and NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a document-based project, and the Document.XIB has this topology:

NSWindow
--> NSTextView (inside NSScrollView)

I want changes in the text view to be tracked by the window and document. Specifically, when text is changed in the text view, the window is marked as edited, and the close button changes state.

From reading [AppKitUndo](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/AppKitUndo.html) it seems that I should set the document as a delegate of the text view, and override the method **undoManagerForTextView:** in the document. But still when I type characters into the text view, the window is not updated (it does not have 'Edited' in the title, and the Exit button is not changed). The state also does not change when I call the document's **updateChangeCount:**. I've also tried setting the window as the delegate, still no success.

Only when I call the window's **setDocumentEdited:** does the window's exit button change state (but the title still does not indicate that the window is changed). I feel like I'm missing a very simple connection in the XIB but it's not clear to me what it is.

Comment: I tried this (document based project, added NSTextView) and the document gets dirty. What did you change?

Comment: @Willeke thanks for testing. As far as I can tell, nothing is changed. I posted a GitHub project with code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: In my project template, the window is connected to the file's owner. The delegate of the window is the file's owner and the window of the file's owner is the window. Did you replace the window?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Willeke, it had to do with exactly what you said. I set up the connections as you said and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today. To properly track the documents edited state, you have to call `NSTextView.breakUndoCoalescing()` in your `NSDocument` subclass when saving the text view's contents:

```
override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {

    let textView = viewController.textView

    textView.breakUndoCoalescing()  <---

    return Data()
}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449384-breakundocoalescing):

> This method should be invoked when saving the receiver’s contents to
>   preserve proper tracking of unsaved changes and the document’s dirty
>   state.